# Erlang case expression not returning value

Tags: encryption, erlang, xmpp, aes, ejabberd

Below is the code snippet I am using to decrypt some XML which is encrypted before. If it is not encrypted (plain text), then I don't need to decrypt and process it, and I want to return it as it is.

It is not returning anything at all. Please help me to make it work.

**Updated code :**

```
pop_offline_messages(Ls, LUser, LServer, odbc) ->
    EUser = ejabberd_odbc:escape(LUser),
    case odbc_queries:get_and_del_spool_msg_t(LServer,
                          EUser)
    of
      {atomic, {selected, [<<"username">>, <<"xml">>], Rs}} ->
      Ls ++
        lists:flatmap(fun ([_, XML]) ->
        ?INFO_MSG("decrypted message from mod_offline ~p ",[XML]),

       Top = case str:str(XML, <<"message">>) of
       Top >= 1 -> XML;
       Top == 0 -> crypto:aes_cfb_128_decrypt(<<"abcdefghabcdefgh">>,<<"12345678abcdefgh">>,base64:decode(XML))
    end,  
           case xml_stream:parse_element(XML) of
                    {error, _Reason} ->
                                          [];
                    El ->
                                          case offline_msg_to_route(LServer, El) of
                                              error ->
                                                  [];
                                              RouteMsg ->
                                                  [RouteMsg]
                                          end
                  end
              end,
              Rs);
      _ -> Ls
    end;
```

Comment: Can you give an example of input data that is supposed to be decrypted?

Comment: I don't see this `crypto:aes_cfb_128_decrypt/3` function in the `crypto` documentation? http://erlang.org/doc/man/crypto_app.html

Comment: What does `str:str/2` do? What value is being returned? Something is **ALWAYS** returned.

Comment: Are you possibly just failing to assign the result to a variable? Judging from `,` at the end, it isn't the last expression in a function.

Comment: You need to be more precise: Does it get stuck ? Does it return an empty value ? Does it trigger an error / exception / exit ?

Answer (score 1):

If it is "not returning anything", it is either because you don't execute it or you don't store the result. I suggest you change your code to:

```
Result = case str:str(XML, <<"message">>) of
      1 -> XML;
      _ -> crypto:aes_cfb_128_decrypt(<<"abcdefghabcdefgh">>,<<"12345678abcdefgh">>,base64:decode(XML))
    end,
io:format("~p~n",[result]),
...
```

because with this current snippet version, the result of the case is not used, so lost as soon as evaluated.

Comment: i tried what you suggested above with storing result but now i am getting below error  Error

Comment: **Error **:  {badmatch,<<"<message from='abc@xyz.com' to='def@xyz.com' xml:lang='en' type='chat' id='aae8a'>\n<body>111111111</body>\n<active xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates'/>\n<request xmlns='urn:xmpp:receipts'/>\n<delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='n.ngageapp.com' stamp='2016-04-11T13:12:12.445Z'>Offline Storage</delay></message>">>},[{mod_offline,'-pop_offline_messages/4-fun-5-',2,[{file,"src/mod_offline.erl"},{line,464}]},{lists,flatmap,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1248}]},{mod_offline,pop_offline_messages,4,[{file,"src/mod_offline.erl"},{line,461}]}

Comment: Difficult to say more, you have a module mod_offline, and line 464 the returned value does not match the pattern you are using (the returned value is a binary string)

Comment: Xml received here may be encrypted/plain text and i am checking if it is encrypted than decrypt before return  it , if palin text than return as it is .